# HTML5 DataList search available language?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

In my datalist options, there are values in English and Korean.

Here is the sample :

```
<input type='text' list='dlValue'>
<datalist id='dlValue'>
<option values='apple'/>
<option values='사과' /> (<-This value is apple in Korean)
```

When I try to search the value with the Korean alphabet in the input box,
there is nothing shown up, only working in English value.

So I am wondering: **how can I make it searchable in Korean?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly checked that issue on Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 and it seemed to be working-ish.

The issue is the input cursor. 
When I typed in Korean in the input, the cursor was not moving forward instead it remained in front of the character and the search seemed to be not working. But if you manually move the cursor then the search worked.

This might be the issue of the browser (I haven't tested that on the other browsers.) or just because of the characteristic of Korean language input system.

Comment: Thanks Jake! I checked in IE (version 11) and the cursor is not moving forward, but after making one Korean word then other available Korean options are shown up. I agree that because of the Korean input system...